# Exceptions causing junk data in string (C#)

Tags: c#, exception

Ok, this is a weird one. The junk data isn't random either, it appears to be substrings of the executable itself.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = GetValue();
    // at this point, s == "400". Why isn't really relevant (dumbed down a test)
    if (s != "18446744073709551615") 
        throw new Exception();
        // When the exception is thrown though, the string is set to random
        // data from inside the executable.
}
```

This seems dependant on certain seemingly insignificant implementation details in GetValue() such as calls to string.Format() being in different places.

Has anyone ever run into something similar or have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: I think you should include GetValue()'s definition no matter how long it is

Comment: Another big question is how are you checking the data in "s", and more importantly "when" are you checking that data? Are you checking it after the exception has been thrown and "s" is now out of scope?

Comment: Yes, this is after VS pops up it's unhandled exception stuff. I can't remember this ever happening before for local variables though.

Comment: And I'm checking it in the "Locals" window in VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"And I'm checking it in the "Locals" window in VS"

That explains it.  Contrary to popular belief, C# is allowed to do some amount of optimization.  If you don't add a "KeepAlive" at the end of your function, the value doesn't really have to be stored.

Comment: Same question to you as Ryan then: why does an integer declared at the start of the function not disappear along with the exception like the string does?

Comment: How do you know if it disappeared or not?  It occupied less space in a different location so it's just less likely to have been stepped on yet.

Comment: Um, also since this is C#, the int is a value type and the string is a reference type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking the variable after the exception has been thrown and is now out of scope, then it should be pointing to nothing more than garbage sitting in memory.  Have you tried checking the value of this variable both before and after the exception has been thrown?

Comment: This seems to be the case... But why does it only seem to happen with a string? If I have an integer with the same scope I can see the value of it fine in the "Locals" windows.